# Customised object using array

Tags: javascript, regex

The below code has a major flaw. The value type is changing. That is the value of  `"limit": 5` and `"skip": 0`  is converting to strings.

```
var arr = [
      'find({ qty: { $lt: 20 } } )',
      'limit(5)',
      'skip(0)'
    ]


var obj = {};

arr.forEach(function(x, n) {
  var m = x.match(/(\w+)\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)/);
  if(n == 0) {
    obj.action = m[1];
    obj.value = m[2];
  } else
    obj[m[1]] = m[2];

});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj,0,3));
```

Expected output:

```
{
   "action": "find",
   "value": "{ qty: { $lt: 20 } }",
   "limit": 5,
   "skip": 0
}
```

Comment: I would presume you'd need to use a parseInt() on that specific string, otherwise it will interpret as a string.

Comment: You are handling strings and making regular expression matches. At no point will the values be considered anything other than strings. They are certainly not changing type.

Comment: This parses into `limit: '5'`. You need to make sure numbers are parsed as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your code is trying to achieve, but you could try casting the values as Numbers before adding them to your object.

Like this:

```
arr.forEach(function(x, n) {
  var m = x.match(/(\w+)\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)/);
  if(n == 0) {
    obj.action = m[1];
    obj.value = !isNaN(m[2]) ? Number(m[2]) : m[2];
  } else
    obj[m[1]] = !isNaN(m[2]) ? Number(m[2]) : m[2];

});
```

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPGJZB?editors=001).

Answer (score 1):

Before assigning `m[2]` to a key in `obj`, check if it is a number. If so, parse it:

```
arr.forEach(function(x, n) {
  var m = x.match(/(\w+)\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)/);
    if(n == 0) {
      obj.action = m[1];
      obj.value = m[2];
    } else{
      var key = m[1], val = m[2];
      if (!isNaN(val)) {
          val = parseInt(val);
      }

      obj[key] = val;
  }
});
```

[Try it in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2q418xa/).

Comment: This assumes the OP doesn't want decimal numbers as values.

Comment: I felt that was a safe assumption given the nature of the object. It appears to be a MongoDB query.